# jquery accordion performance

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-accordion

Does anyone know how many elements a jQuery accordion can handle before performance becomes a problem?  I have a nested accordion structure with ten items at the root level, and then a handful of nested items within each root item down to a nesting level of three or four.  Performance is unusable.  It isn't great even with two levels.  Anyone got any words of wisdom?

Comment: How about a link to a page that reproduces the problem? It's semi-impossible to say without seeing any code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For information, IE7 started struggling with a few hundred entries sprinkled over three levels.  Chrome was fine.  If you are considering using the accordion I would recommend testing with realistic volumes before committing to that technique.